# npm run migrate asking for password

Tags: migrate

I'm running into a wall when it comes to migrating to databases. For some reason whenever I try to migrate git bash asks me for a password. A password I never had to enter before.

I don't know what this password could be. I tried my desktop password but that gives me the same error as if I put nothing at all.

> ```
> $ npm run migrate
> ```
>
> > express-boilerplate@0.0.1 migrate C:\Users\Zackr\Documents\node\node-todo-get-post
> > postgrator --config postgrator-config.js
>
> Password:
> C:\Users\Zackr\Documents\node\node-todo-get-post\node_modules\postgrator-cli\postgrator-cli.js:187
> rl.history = rl.history.slice(1);
> ^
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined
> at C:\Users\Zackr\Documents\node\node-todo-get-post\node_modules\postgrator-cli\postgrator-cli.js:187:33
> at Interface._onLine (readline.js:335:5)
> at Interface._normalWrite (readline.js:482:12)
> at Socket.ondata (readline.js:194:10)
> at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
> at addChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:309:12)
> at readableAddChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:284:9)
> at Socket.Readable.push (internal/streams/readable.js:223:10)
> at Pipe.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:188:23) npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR!
> express-boilerplate@0.0.1 migrate: `postgrator --config postgrator-config.js` npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed
> at the express-boilerplate@0.0.1 migrate script. npm ERR! This is
> probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging
> output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
> C:\Users\Zackr\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2021-02-17T21_50_59_429Z-debug.log

Answer (score 0):

Didn't realize that the new version of postgrator-cli requires a password. I rolled back to an earlier version.